# Energy of small E-Paper display modules

Tags: power-consumption

Has anyone used small 2"- 4" [epaper modules](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/serial-2-9-inch-e-paper-screen-128x296-for-electronic-shelf-label-lcd) similar to these, and measured the actual energy consumption of them?

e.g. in J/erase/write or J per 1/4 rewrite.

Have you compared the power crossover point with any low power LCDs?

e.g epaper is more efficient at less than N writes/hour?

Compared with say [this at 80uA](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/graphic-display/122x32-dots?cotroller_ic=436) or [this at 450uA](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/2-6-inch-128x64-cog-lcd-module-display-serial-spi-white-blue) or your alternative suggestion.

Any other pearls of experience with them?

---

Yes I can read the datasheet current. The best info I have found is an [old silabs app note](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN0063.pdf) indicating ~40mJ/update.

Comment: I would suspect this is the type of stuff you find in datasheets. I also don't know how much the ratio of black/white pixels impacts this

Comment: Can't reach the websites in Firefox - SSL_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED_ALERT

Comment: I use FF and they are OK for me.

Comment: The datasheet of you e-paper module is accessible from the link you gave. Why don't you read it? It says: "*Standby panel current: 0.6µA*" and "*Image update current: 11mA*". You have the controller reference given: SSD1675A, whose [datasheet is available too](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/SSD1675A.pdf). I'm too lazy to read that, but it will surely say somewhere the image update time required. From there, it is easy to deduce the crossover point.

Comment: That's why I haven't made an actual answer. Now, you should state in your question that you have read the datasheet and acknowledged the power consumption written there, but, for some reason (indicate it), you have doubts and want that to be confirmed by someone who actually measured it. Otherwise, it makes no sense. Also, you don't have to be disrespectful. I haven't been (although I reckon I  assumed you didn't read the datasheet - but this isn't disrespectful, is it?).

Comment: @JorenVaes  In the past I saw some comparisons of the work-function of electrophoresis vs other just-about-to-be-the-next-big-thing non-volatile displays. It was a fairly complex function of content refresh modes/percentages, epaper characteristics. Hence I would like to hear of someone who has used these